# Spring boot error when including camel-cxf

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel

I create a project with following pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.pratama</groupId>
        <artifactId>belajar</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>spring-cxf</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <properties>
        <spring.boot.version>1.4.2.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
        <spring.batch.version>2.2.0.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
        <camel.version>2.17.6</camel.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Camel -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
            <version>${camel.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

You can see there is a camel-cxf dependency which i need to use in my project. I can run other camel components perfectly such as camel-jetty, camel-http, camel-servlet and camel-jdbc without any issue.

This is error log in my tomcat when the cxf project is running:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.4.2.RELEASE)

2017-04-28 15:14:56.916  INFO 6696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.pratama.belajar.cxf.Main             : Starting Main on DESKTOP-HF8TECD with PID 6696 (C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\webapps\spring-cxf\WEB-INF\classes started by gimel in C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-8.5.14)
2017-04-28 15:14:56.931  INFO 6696 --- [ost-startStop-1] com.pratama.belajar.cxf.Main             : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-04-28 15:14:56.985  INFO 6696 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@28712258: startup date [Fri Apr 28 15:14:56 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-28 15:14:59.577 ERROR 6696 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:64) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:102) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForBeanMethod(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:178) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:140) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:333) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) ~[spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: @ConditionalOnMissingBean did not specify a bean using type, name or annotation and the attempt to deduce the bean's type failed
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.validate(OnBeanCondition.java:310) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:300) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnBeanCondition.java:112) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        ... 30 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanTypeDeductionException: Failed to deduce bean type for org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration.jpaVendorAdapter
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:373) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanType(OnBeanCondition.java:347) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.<init>(OnBeanCondition.java:294) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1868) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510) ~[spring-core-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnBeanCondition$BeanSearchSpec.addDeducedBeanTypeForBeanMethod(OnBeanCondition.java:360) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119) ~[catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        ... 41 common frames omitted

2017-04-28 15:14:59.578  INFO 6696 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@28712258: startup date [Fri Apr 28 15:14:56 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-04-28 15:14:59.587  WARN 6696 --- [ost-startStop-1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception thrown from LifecycleProcessor on context close

java.lang.IllegalStateException: LifecycleProcessor not initialized - call 'refresh' before invoking lifecycle methods via the context: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@28712258: startup date [Fri Apr 28 15:14:56 ICT 2017]; root of context hierarchy
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getLifecycleProcessor(AbstractApplicationContext.java:415) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.doClose(AbstractApplicationContext.java:975) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.close(AbstractApplicationContext.java:934) [spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:818) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86) [spring-boot-1.4.2.RELEASE.jar:1.4.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169) [spring-web-4.3.4.RELEASE.jar:4.3.4.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823) [catalina.jar:8.5.14]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]

28-Apr-2017 15:14:59.588 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start:
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-cxf]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/beans/factory/ObjectProvider
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2625)
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1868)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:537)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:683)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:627)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:597)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1445)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:445)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:415)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:530)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:523)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBeansOfType(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1162)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromMappedException(SpringApplication.java:886)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.getExitCodeFromException(SpringApplication.java:872)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleExitCode(SpringApplication.java:858)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.handleRunFailure(SpringApplication.java:812)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:151)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:131)
        at org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:86)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.beans.factory.ObjectProvider
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1285)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
        ... 38 more

28-Apr-2017 15:14:59.590 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-8.5.14\webapps\spring-cxf.war
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/spring-cxf]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:756)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:952)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1823)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Try with newer versions

Comment: thanks, i can run it with the newer version